# Pyspark Split result does not contain the remaining string

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, split, databricks

I would like to split as a string as "23220" to an array [2,3,2,20]. I tried

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([('23220',)], ['s',])
df.select(f.split(str=df.s, pattern='', limit=4).alias('s')).show()
```

However, this returns [2,3,2,2 ]. Even the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) says:

> limit > 0: The resulting array’s length will not be more than limit, and the resulting array’s last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched pattern.

I noticed this phenomenon did not exist with Databricks Version 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12) but with  Databricks Version 11.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12) and newer.

Comment: Try adding a delimiter between the last two digits of the string.

Comment: The string is fix, I cannot adjust it

Comment: you could use `substring()` functions, and then create an array using their results

Comment: @samkart can you provide an example?

Comment: @LazlooXp what is your pyspark version?

Comment: As described written above. I Use Spark Version 11 and 12

Comment: Following @samkart suggestion you can write `df.select(f.array(f.substring(df.s, 1, 1), f.substring(df.s, 2, 1), f.substring(df.s, 3, 1), f.substring(df.s, 4, 2)).alias('s')).show()`

Comment: Version 11 and 12, is that your scala version? What is the version of spark? The latest is 3.4.1. For instance I could not reproduce your issue in spark 3.3.2. the `limit` argument was introduced in `3.0` so it has to be `>=3.0`.

Comment: Your version of java might help as well. > Spark runs on Java 8/11/17, Scala 2.12/2.13, Python 3.7+, and R 3.5+. Python 3.7 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.4.0. Java 8 prior to version 8u362 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.4.0.

Comment: could the version mean [databricks runtime version](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/releases.html)? i'm not able to replicate the stated behavior on spark 3.4 and 3.2.

Comment: I edit the Description: It does not happen with Databricks Version 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12) but with  Databricks Version 11.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12) and newer

Comment: @LazlooXp, which databricks are you using? azure,aws or community?

Comment: I am using AWS.

Comment: What about when you use the pattern `'|'`?

Comment: Wow, that works @Lamanus. How can I interpret ``'|'`` ?

Comment: that is a usual char separator and empty is weird one.

Comment: Can you write this as an official answer? I would check mark this. @Lamanus